# Trouble using input value in function angular

Tags: angular, function, variables, input

I am making a login form for a school project using angular, the html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" />
<input type="text" ng-model="password" name="password" />
<button (click)="submit(username, password)">Login</button>
```

I have the submit function defined in the typescript file associated with this component, when I try to run the function I get an error because my variables aren't properly defined.
My goal here is to take the input text from the login and password sections and insert them into the submit function when the button is pressed, I thought the ng-model definition would do this but I am new to angular so I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]`. It'll bind each input to `username` and `password` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Angular (2+) and not AngularJS(1.x). If this is the case then you should use `ngModel` instead of `ng-model`

Comment: Hey, I tried this but the only change is that now I see 'username' and 'password' in my input fields before I input something myself, the variables are still undefined when I press Login. The submit function itself is contained within a typescript file and tries to retrieve the variables by calling: submit(username, password). I was assuming it would recognize username and password as the variables in the html file because they are part of the same component, is this the right way of retrieving variables?

Comment: Have you used `[(ngModel)]` for 2-ways data binding?

Answer (score 0):

Use your inputs inside a form tag,

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" />
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" />
<button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with the tag you put in your question (Angular 2+).

The way you use `ngModel` on the HTML is this way:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" />
<button (click)="submit()">Login</button>
```

*You need to import the `Forms Module` to be able to use ngModel*

In your TS file:

```
username: string;

submit(){
    //do whatever you want accessing the variable this way: this.username
}
```

You could use a form, but that is explained on other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" [(ngmodel)]="username" name="username">
<input type="text" [(ngmodel)]="password" name="password">
<button (click)="submit()">Login</button>
```

in component.ts firstly define fields for two-way binding

```
public username:any;
public password:any
```

in submit function

```
submit(){
//call fields 
this.username
this.password
}
```

I hope you imported formsmodule in appmoodule(root-module)

Comment: This method is most optimum.What is the use of ngModel if you are just passing them as argument like in submit(username,password). ngModel is used for two way binding.In industry this optimum practice is followed rest is upto you.